# Call a restfull API with authentication in php EDIT : Security

Tags: php, rest, api, restful-authentication

hi thank you for reading.

I did my http query to call a restfull API. It require a user name and password so I put it in the query(refer to the code bellow). I wanted the user (colleagues) to enter user name and password to put them in the query. In this way they can access the Data from the api they have rights on. But it is not an internal api so I ask myself on how I can make the query secured so the informations would not be intercepted.

Here is what i try to do :

```
<?php
$username="user";
$passw="password";
$url="https://domaine.dom/api/path/to/file";
$params = array('limits' => '10', );

$header = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');



//add the http authentication to the header
function addBasicAuth($header, $username, $password) {
    $header['Authorization'] = 'Basic '.base64_encode("$username:$password");
    return $header;
}

// method should be "GET", "PUT", etc..
function request($method, $url, $header, $params) {
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => $method,
    ),
);

// serialize the header if needed
if (!empty($header)) {
    $header_str = '';
    foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
        $header_str .= "$key: $value\r\n";
    }
    $header_str .= "\r\n";
    $opts['http']['header'] = $header_str;
}

// serialize the params if there are any
if (!empty($params)) {
    $params_array = array();
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $params_array[] = "$key=$value";
    }
    $url .= '?'.implode('&', $params_array);
}


//create flow context with option array completed with authentication informations
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
//get content in json ($header['Content-Type']=>'application/json')
//get back content in json
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
return $data;
}

$header = addBasicAuth($header, $username, $password);
/*after we call this function we have :
$header=array('Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => Basic.base64("$username:$password")
);*/
$response = request("GET", $url, $header, $params);//create context, create request and launch it
echo $response;




/* code i tried to do myself
$authstring= $username.":".$passw;
$encodeauth= base64_encode($authstring);
$options = array('httpauth' => $encodeauth, );
$reponse=http_get($url, $options);
echo $reponse;
*/
?>
```

Comment: Turn on errors: error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1); Let us know what gets displayed.

Comment: Also try with var_dump($response) and see what outputs.

Comment: Well i did a var_dump (I always do but not this time ?!?) and i saw my data ! so i reload the page with only echo $response; and i works .. I definitely don't know what was wrong, i had no error but no return. Can it comes from the server where data is hosted ?